# Is batt_attr_text file vendor-independent in Android

Tags: android, battery, batterylevel

I would like to know whether in Android the batt_attr_text file's location and content is the same regardless of the vendor or not? (Btw. same content means now that it has the same "attributes" listed in it...)

The reason I ask this is because of another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439619/getting-the-battery-current-values-for-the-android-phone). In the mentioned question, the questioner wants to know Voltage and Current. He/She gets an answer indicating, that the information can be found in a vendor-dependent file.

However what I'm looking for is the mAh capacity of the battery. I found that /sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_attr_text contains what I need, but I'm not sure, that this file will be found on every Android device in the same form and in the same place.

Every constructive answer is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's device specific, so it depends on the manufacturer. Have a look at this project: https://code.google.com/p/currentwidget/