# Android get charge rate in milliamps via sysfs

Tags: android, sysfs

I am developing a informational android app where I want to read the charge rate in milli-amps when the device is charging. I have seen other apps that can do this such as Ampere.

I believe the info should be in directory `/sys/class/power_supply/battery` which of these files are relevant in accomplishing this, and how could I calculate charge rate in mA from this?

Comment: Anyone? I can post these file names and contents if it would help. Was hoping to hear from someone who's done this before.

Comment: You may take a look for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439619/getting-the-battery-current-values-for-the-android-phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directory may change according to the phone manufacturer. See this link for supporting more devices [currentwidget](https://github.com/rmanor/currentwidget/blob/master/CurrentWidgetLibrary/src/com/manor/currentwidget/library/CurrentReaderFactory.java)

And above API 21+ charge counter and energy counter is implemented: see the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER)

Comment: This appears to be the same value as read from file in accepted answer. Good to know though.

Comment: sure but as i know the current value file is not the same for all devices. That is why many cases were implemented in the currentwidget app to support almost all devices.

Comment: Ah I see I missed that part. I apologize this should have received the bounty.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [linux kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/power_supply_class.txt), you can read the charge rate from `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/current_now`. The value is in µA, so you should scale it by 1000. Negative values mean that the device is charging.

Comment: Tested this today, this value seems to be accurate but the value doesn't become negative until 20-30 seconds after I begin charging the device. And then when unplugging the device it stays negative for 20-30 seconds before becoming positive. Is this normal?