# BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW not working on every device. What are alternatives?

Tags: java, android

My app uses BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW to get the battery current of the device:

```
BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);
int current = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW), context);
```

However, it does not work for example on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A. There it returns just 0.

Other apps show the current even on that device. How do they do it? What are alternatives to my method?

Comment: have you tried something like this [get-battery-level-and-state-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the battery current values for the Android Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439619/getting-the-battery-current-values-for-the-android-phone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question ("returns just 0") please take a look at the documentation on getIntProperty:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager#getIntProperty(int)

If the property is not supported or there is any other error, return

**(a) 0 if targetSdkVersion < VERSION_CODES.P**

or

(b) Integer.MIN_VALUE if targetSdkVersion >= VERSION_CODES.P.

Comment: So, it is just not supported on some devices… That explains it at least.

Answer (score -1):

Use this method:

```
int getBatteryPercent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    if (intent != null) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        return level * 100 / scale;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this :

```
BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);

    int current = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL), context)
```

Comment: where's the difference, beside the introduced syntax errors?