# ACCESS PERMISSION to read "/sys/class/power_supply/Battery/current_now" in Android Studio (Huawei P20)

Tags: android, file-permissions, battery

everyone. I tried to access file "/sys/class/power_supply/Battery/current_now" to retrieve the battery current in Huawei P20.

```
f =  File("/sys/class/power_supply/Battery/current_now");
if (f.exists()) {
  return OneLineReader.getValue(f, true)
```

However i get the error of

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/Battery/current_now: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

i already grant permission of read and write to storage.

```
private val PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

fun verifyStoragePermissions(activity: Activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    val permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
    }
}
```

Anyone has the hint for this problem?

Comment: current_now is file or folder???

Comment: current_now is file

Comment: what are the extension??

Comment: i wonder that file is system file and need access through "root" or other way to read the file.

Comment: i use the method in this page.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439619/getting-the-battery-current-values-for-the-android-phone

Comment: You are trying to access system files, even if you grant external read and write permission, you probably won't be able to access it on non-rooted device. Also its part of the internal storage and not the external one.

Comment: Other model of phone that use this method does not have any problem, such as XiaoMi. However, problem arises when using Huawei P20. I am not sure whether new version of android has new permission to this directory.

Comment: Looks like targetSdk affects too. When I target on api 21 i can read the file even with enforced selinux and no root. But now i'm updating my app to targetSdk=28 and experiencing same issue. The working code doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need turn off selinux. 
Use `adb shell "setenforce 0"` and then you can read it from your app

Comment: Permission denied for above