# How to get battery current (mA) from android device

Tags: java, android-studio, batterymanager

I have this problem:
I have created an application for monitoring the phone battery values.
On my samsung, I can get battery current in mA with `BatteryManager` and property `BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW`, but on other android devices with same OS version (7.0) I am not able to reach right number, there is some insane value.

Other application AccuBattery on the same device showing the right values, so where is the problem?

Is there another way how to get battery current or power consumption?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439619/getting-the-battery-current-values-for-the-android-phone

Comment: yes, it is working good on my samsung but on other device it is not.\